# Подскажите как можно получить данные с сайта

Tags: xml, xpath

Сайт автотека,конкретная ссылка https://autoteka.ru/report_by_ad/1814203589?utm_source=avito.ru&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=teaser.

```xml
<div class="_3UbwE"><div class="_3qZQB"><span class="_2qaUO">VIN:</span> <span title="LFAC*************">LFAC*************</span></div><div class="_3qZQB"><span class="_2qaUO">Год выпуска:</span> <span title="2008">2008</span></div><div class="_3qZQB"><span class="_2qaUO">Тип ТС:</span> <span title="Легковой универсал">Легковой универсал</span></div><div class="_3qZQB"><span class="_2qaUO">Объем двигателя:</span> <span title="2 261 см³">2 261 см³</span></div><div class="_3qZQB"><span class="_2qaUO">Мощность:</span> <span title="146 л.с.">146 л.с.</span></div></div>
```

Каким способом можно получить с сайта значение поля " VIN:"?

Пробовал использовать IMPORTXML: 
=IMPORTXML(https://autoteka.ru/report_by_ad/1814203589?utm_source=avito.ru&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=teaser;//*)
загружается информация, но там нет поля vin.

Пробовал подставлять код элемента:
=IMPORTXML(https://autoteka.ru/report_by_ad/1814203589?utm_source=avito.ru&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=teaser;//a[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2])
Результат: #НД

Comment: Приведите кусок html/xml, откуда нужно вытащить данные. Все данные не нужны, только конкретно это место. Нужно именно текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Есть сайт, из которого мне нужно значение поля vin. Проблема в том, что я не знаю какое конкретно место мне нужно вытащить (чайник).

Comment: Правой кнопкой тыкаете, выбираете `Исходный код страницы`, поиском находите место, которое нужно xpath вытащить, копируете место и вокруг него и вставляете в вопрос. Для парсинга html как правильно нужно опираться на значения в атрибутах `class` и `id`, можно и по другим атрибутам, но эти двое основные "помощники"

Comment: <span title="LFAC*************">LFAC*************</span>

Comment: Добавил сам. Кст, содержимое страницы приходит не все -- остальное подгружается и рендерится, поэтому нужно не просто скачать страницы, но и выполнить ее браузерным движком, иначе контент не получите. Я бы попробовал реализовать это на selenium